# $n$-th homology group of a particular product space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

1- Let $I$ be a finite set and for every $i \in I$, let $S_i$ be an arbitrary subspace of $[0,1]$ (endowed with its usual topology).
Moreover, let $S := \prod_{i \in I} S_i$ (endowed with product topology).

Does for every $n > 0$, $H_n(S) \simeq \{0\}$ (where $H_n(S)$ is the $n$-th singular homology group of $S$) ? If not, do we have sufficient conditions on $(S_i)_{i \in I}$ to obtain that $H_n(S) \simeq \{0\}$ ?

2- More generally, let $I$ be a set and for every $i \in I$, let $X_i$ be an arbitrary topological space.
Moreover, let $X := \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ (endowed with product topology).

How do we determine, for every $n > 0$, $H_n(X)$ ?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you know the Künneth formula?

Comment: No, I did not know about that theorem, thank you. I took a look on Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem), but I am not very familiar with tensor product (I will have a look). But for my first point, is it so complicated ? I have the feeling that the homology groups in that case have to be trivials (as a kind of disjoint union of contractible spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path components of any subset $S_i \subset I$ are intervals (which may be degenerate to points), in particular they are contractible.

The path components $P_\alpha$ of $S$ are the products of the path components of the $S_i$, hence contractible. Since
$$H_n(S) = \sum_\alpha H_n(P_\alpha) ,$$
we get $H_n(S) = 0$ for $n > 0$ and $H_0(S) =  \sum_\alpha \mathbb Z$ which is a free abelian group whose rank equals the cardinality of the sets of path components of $S$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. Thank you for your help !